# Pricipled Volume

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine, image

attached is the same picture rendered with Eevee engine with the shader '*Principled Volume*' applied on the left.
I have used a Light '*Spot*' for the torch.
As we can see I get that glitch on the torch, sort of pixelated effect, highlighted in the red circle, do you know how to fix it?

Thanks.
[image]

---

Lower the volumetric *Tile Size* helped, thanks.
However why I can see the light through the body of the Torch? See the red dotted area.[image]

I get some improvements playing with '*Volumetrics --> End, Tile Size, Samples*' and with '*Volumetric Lighting --> Light Clamping*'
[image: Volumetrics Parameters]

Comment: You need to tweak some values to make the volumetrics look better: In the Render panel play with the Sampling values, and also in the Render panel, under Volumetrics, play with Tile Size (lower is better) and Samples

Comment: As per the problem of the light leaking through the body of the torch it seems to be a limitation in Eevee blender.stackexchange.com/a/214915/85951, thanks @Geri for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to lower your volumetric *Tile Size*. Keep in mind that lower values can drastically increase render times in more complex scenes. See which is the highest value you deem "good enough".

[image]

[image]